# Get-StoredCredential does not work anymore with Windows Credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, credentials, credential-manager

Maybe I am wrong, but this used to work previously in my Windows 10 machine, now I recognize I can not run anymore in my Windows 11 machine:

It works for Generic Credentials, but does not work with Windows Credentials, tried multiple credentials. The command returns with an empty object.

```
$credential = Get-StoredCredential -Target TERMSRV/my-credential-name-exactly-as-i-see-in-credential-manager
```